# Debug a report using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, visual-studio-debugging

I have a problem with my SSRS report when it runs from Dynamic ax 2012. I debugged it and I found out that the problem is with my SSRS report that I created in Visual Studio. I want to debug it there, but when I want to "*Attach to process*" I can't find `ReportingServicesService.exe`, because my Report Service is located on another server.

Please help me: what should I do to debug SSRS reports in Visual Studio?

I have SQL Server 2008, Visual Studio 2010, and ax 2012.

The problem is that I didn't write any code in my report: I just use a data provider in my report, but debugging the data provider code shows that the problem is in my report.

Answer (score 5):

A way you can test your report is to create labels with the parameters values and othes, just to be sure that the filters or the calculated values are ok.

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid that what you seem to want **is not possible**: there is no way to set breakpoints in reports and debug them like you would a regular .NET app. You haven't specified what type of problem you're facing, but in general you'll have to resort to more basic "debugging" techniques:

- In some cases [binary search](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50552/how-to-effectively-do-manual-debugging/181223#181223) may be your best bet
- If you have a clue on where the problem lies you may be able to debug that part seperately (say the data shown is incorrect, so you could debug the query seperately, in a different tool such as SSMS)
- As mentioned by @Rednaxel you can use "printf-debugging" to check parameters, expressions, etc.

If you've narrowed down the problem but can't find a solution you can always ask a question about that problem here, of course.

Comment: This is correct but this is one of the most frustrating things about SSRS development. They're total black boxes and sometimes they don't work and it's incredibly difficult to find out what the solution is. For example right now I'm just getting "An error occurred in your report" that's it...no reason why or what's wrong with it. (shakes fist impotently at sky)